# Files included with // instead of http:// are not loaded

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, php-phantomjs

I try to get all links of a html construct generated by a script. The script is included like this: //server.de/script1.js

The JavaScript-file is not loaded. If I change the // to http:// there is no problem. How to load files with // ?

```
var page  = require('webpage').create();
var system = require('system');

page.onError = function(msg, trace) {
  console.log(msg);
  phantom.exit();
};

var startProcess;

function process() {
  var links = page.evaluate( function() {   
  phantom.exit();
}

page.onResourceReceived = function(requestData, request) {
  clearTimeout(startProcess);
  startProcess = setTimeout(function() {
    process();
  }, 3000);
};

var content = '<script async="async" type="text/javascript" src="//server.de/script.js"></script>';

page.content = content;
```

I get a timeout this way.

Comment: Is it possible that the page is being served over an `https:` URL so that `//` resolves to `https://`, while the `server.de` server only serves the resource over `http://`?

Comment: `page.setContent(content, "http://server.de")` should do the trick

Comment: This solved it problem!